# Div id display only on If mobile detected results nothing using javsacript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to display div id only on mobile device detect. when I am testing on mobile device I put alert message for mobiles it is showing fine, but div id not displaying on mobile devices, just showing blank screen. Here is my code please check where I am wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
if(isMobile.any()){
alert('mobile');    
$("#dialog").show();
}
else{
$("#dialog").hide();
}
</script>

</head>    
<body>
<div id="dialog"  style=" display: none"title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
<input class="myInput" type="text" />
<button class="formSaver">Save me!</button>
</div>       
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(isMobile.any()){
        alert('mobile');    
        $("#dialog").show();
    }
    else{
      $("#dialog").hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your script to following. use `document ready`.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(isMobile.any()){
       alert('mobile');    
       $("#dialog").show();
    } else {
       $("#dialog").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

For reference - https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your dialog div element

```
style=" display: none"
```

remove it.